# Outputting results from select box option in options panel

Tags: theme-options, options

I'm trying to figure out how to get the results from a select box option and apply them to my theme. When I use a text input or color picker it works fine. But when I use a select box, nothing is changing. Here's the option:

```
$options['color_scheme'] = array(
        'name' => __('Color Scheme', 'text-domain'),
        'desc' => __('Select a color scheme.', 'text-domain'),
        'id' => 'color_scheme',
        'std' => 'blue',
        'type' => 'select',
        'class' => 'mini',
        'options' => array('blue', 'yellow'));
```

This code below is where I'm trying to output certain option based on the selection:

```
if ( of_get_option('color_scheme') == "blue") {
                $output .= "#header {background:#000066;}\n";
            }
    else if ( of_get_option('color_scheme') == "yellow") {
                $output .= "#header {background:#FFFF66;}\n";
            }

if ($output <> '') {
            $output = "<!-- Custom Styling -->\n<style type=\"text/css\">\n" . $output . "</style>\n";
            echo $output;
        }
```

Comment: **Is that your full code?** You are not printing your `$output` you are only storing it in a variable. If it is `echo` your result instead. Also, keep your `else if` together like `elseif` otherwise it can break if you ever use that syntax style without curly braces.

Comment: @userabuser No, that's not my full code. I've added the portion of the code where I print the output. Note that it works fine for input variables and color pickers. I'm just running into a problem with the select box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the same options framework plugin and this is how I specify a select menu using this framework;

```
$test_array = array(
    'one' => __('One', 'options_framework_theme'),
    'two' => __('Two', 'options_framework_theme'),
    'three' => __('Three', 'options_framework_theme'),
    'four' => __('Four', 'options_framework_theme'),
    'five' => __('Five', 'options_framework_theme')
);

$options[] = array(
    'name' => __('Select a Tag', 'options_check'),
    'desc' => __('Passed an array of tags with term_id and term_name', 'options_check'),
    'id' => 'example_select_tags',
    'type' => 'select',
    'options' => $test_array);
```

Note that the `options` parameter accepts;

```
'options' => array('value' => 'label')
```

Where as in your instance you have only specified the label using;

```
'options' => array('blue', 'yellow')
```

Which means blue has a value of `0` and yellow has a value of `1`.

Therefore the following is incorrect,

```
if ( of_get_option('color_scheme') == "blue")
```

As it should be,

```
if ( of_get_option('color_scheme') == 0) //0 for blue 1 for yellow
```

If you want to check by a value name of blue or yellow then your array should look like,

```
'options' => array(
    'blue' => 'Blue',
    'yellow' => 'Yellow'
 )
```

Comment: Thank you. Accepted and upvoted. I didn't realize the array needed to be a key/value pair. Works beautifully.